# Вводное слово или нет?

Tags: синтаксис

Почему в предложении "Рецепты общения по Карнеги незамысловаты"
по Карнеги - не выделяется запятыми, ведь это вводные слова (источник сообщения - по словам Карнеги)?

Answer (score 1):

Вводные слова не связаны грамматически с другими словами в предложении. Здесь же: рецепты (какие?) по Карнеги - определение.

Answer (score 0):

Если бы в тексте было "по словам Карнеги", или "по мнению Карнеги",или "согласно книгам Карнеги", то налицо были бы источники сообщения (слова, книги, мнение), но этих слов в приведенном предложении нет, поэтому "по Карнеги" не выделено запятыми.

Comment: Понятно. Но мы же можем сэкономить "мнению, словам". Как-то в ЕГЭ были такие примеры. Правда, они стояли в начале предложения. Может, поэтому нагрузка у них другая? (По Цветаевой, ... По мне, ...).

Answer (score 0):

Ирина, все верно, можем сэкономить. Но, как уже отметил Виктор, смысла у предложения может быть два. Выделение запятыми ("Рецепты общения, по Карнеги, незамысловаты") будет говорить о ссылке на авторитет Карнеги. Отсутствие запятых будет говорить о принадлежности "рецептов общения" автору Карнеги. То есть слова "по Карнеги" будут выполнять функцию определения, как указал Лаpf.